# codemagic distribution firebase

Tags: firebase, codemagic

please can i get some help about , firebase distribution from codemagic ? When i finished building the app , i don't know why it doesn't publish himself to firebase. It always give me an error , like it show below here:

[image]

In tried to resolve the problem by trying to associate it to google play , i saw here https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038 , but i am not getting even the possibility to associate , like it showing down here:

[image]

Comment: Please read the tag descriptor before using a tag. The `distribution` tag is for statistical distributions, not software distribution.

Answer (score 0):

check you completed following steps:

- The app is registered with your Firebase project and your Google Play developer account. This means that you have both a Firebase Android App and a Google Play app.
- The app in Google Play and the Firebase Android App are both registered using the same package name.
- The app in Google Play is setup on the app dashboard, and it has the following status:

  - The app is distributed on one of the following Google Play tracks: Internal testing, Closed testing, Open testing, or Production.
  - The app's review in Google Play is complete and the app is published. Your app is published if the App status column displays one of the following statuses: Internal (not Draft Internal Testing), Closed testing, Open testing, or Production.